# Java get single element from webpage

Tags: java, web, controls, element

Hi so after some searching still not found an answer but i would like to get a single element of a webpage to a String Variable. I know how to do this in C but would like to know in java

eg:

```
document.nav(the webpage)
String value = document.getElementbyid(theid)
```

Thanks

so eg:

some webpage has

```
<body>
<P id=element1>the value i want</p>
</body>
```

and i need to get that value from the webpage into a String variable

Comment: What exactly would you like to get? The complete html of the element including tags or the text. Short minimal example html would be helpful too. And what is the type of document (or what is your input data (InputStream, Url, String or ...))?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772828/how-to-parse-html-table-using-jsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for that:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com"; // or whatever goes here
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(false).timeout(60000/*wait up to 60 sec for response*/).get();
String value = document.body().select("#element1" /*css selector*/).get(0).text();
```

If you need another input format please refer to [the cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/)

It's not really necessary to specify timeout ect. for the connection. You could just use

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

I only included the timeout if the webpage takes really long to load. You also may want to follow redirects.