# How to parse HTML table using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML using jsoup. This is my first time working with jsoup and I read some tutorial on it as well. Below is my HTML table which I am trying to parse -

If you see my below table, it has three `tr` as of now (I have shorten it down to have three table rows just for understanding purpose but in general it will be more). Now I would like to extract `Cluster Name` from my below table and it's corresponding `host name` so for example - I would extract `Titan` as cluster name and all its hostname whose status are down.

As you can see below for `Titan` cluster name, I have two hostnames `machineA.abc.com` and `machineB.abc.com` in which `machineA` status is `up` but `machineB` status is `down`.

So I will print out `Titan` as cluster name and print out `machineB.abc.com` as the hostname since it is down. Is this possible to do using jsoup?

```
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Alert</td>
      <td>Cluster Name</td>
      <td>IP addr</td>
      <td>Host Name</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Free</td>
      <td>Version</td>
      <td>Restart Time</td>
      <td>UpTime(Days)</td>
      <td>Last probed</td>
      <td>Last up</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td>Titan</td>
      <td>10.100.111.77</td>
      <td>machineA.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">up</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>88%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:49:08,220</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>381</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.200.192.99</td>
      <td>machineB.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">down</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>85%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:52:20,613</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>103</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So far, I am able to extract whole HTML table using jsoup but not sure how would I extract cluster name and the hostnames which are down -

```
URL url = new URL("url_name");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
```

**Update:-**

I might have two cluster name in the table as shown below -

```
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Alert</td>
      <td>Cluster Name</td>
      <td>IP addr</td>
      <td>Host Name</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Free</td>
      <td>Version</td>
      <td>Restart Time</td>
      <td>UpTime(Days)</td>
      <td>Last probed</td>
      <td>Last up</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td>Titan</td>
      <td>10.100.111.77</td>
      <td>machineA.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">up</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>88%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:49:08,220</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>381</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.200.192.99</td>
      <td>machineB.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">down</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>85%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:52:20,613</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>103</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td>Goldy</td>
      <td>10.100.111.77</td>
      <td>machineH.pqr.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">up</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>88%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:49:08,220</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>381</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>       
</table>
```

Now if you see above I have two cluster name - one is `Titan` and other is `Goldy` so I want to find all the machines which are down for `Titan` cluster name only.

Comment: Just a side note to anybody working with fragments of HTML: JSoup is not able to parse `<tr>` without a `<table>`. Easiest solution is to wrap the string with `<table></table>` before parsing it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JSoup. First, you select the table. Then, you select the `<tr>` tags for rows. You can start from the second index since the first row contains only the column names. Then loop over the `<th>` tags and get the specific index. In your case, the indexes 7 and 5 are important(index 7: Status, index 5: Host Name). Check the status if it equals to `down` and if it is, then add the Host Name to a list. That's all.

```
ArrayList<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
Elements rows = table.select("tr");

for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { //first row is the col names so skip it.
    Element row = rows.get(i);
    Elements cols = row.select("td");

    if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down")) {
        downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());
    }
}
```

**Update:**
When you find the word `Titan` you can create another loop and look if the cluster name is empty.

**Edit:** I change the `while` loop to `do while` loop.

```
    ArrayList<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
    Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");

    for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { //first row is the col names so skip it.
        Element row = rows.get(i);
        Elements cols = row.select("td");

        if (cols.get(3).text().equals("Titan")) {
            if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down"))
                downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());

            do {
                if(i < rows.size() - 1)
                   i++;
                row = rows.get(i);
                cols = row.select("td");
                if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down") && cols.get(3).text().equals("")) {
                    downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());
                }
                if(i == rows.size() - 1)
                    break;
            }
            while (cols.get(3).text().equals(""));
            i--; //if there is two Titan names consecutively.
        }
    }
```

downServers ArrayList will contain the list of down servers hostnames.

Comment: Yup it works fine. But there is one problem. I have updated the question just now. I need to find out the down servers only for `Titan` cluster name. Is that  also possible?

Comment: Yes, you can change the if condition. if(cols.get(7).text().equals("down") && cols.get(3).text().equals("Titan"))

Comment: somehow it doesn't work since cluster name is not in every row, only the first time it is there and then host nnames related to that cluster. And then another cluster name followed by its host names.

Comment: See the update, I couldn't test it but i think it will work for your case.

Comment: I just tried it and somehow it doesn't work. Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: Uups my bad, change if(i > rows.size() - 1) to if(i < rows.size() - 1)

Answer (score 7):

What I would do in your case is first create an Object of your machine with all apropriate attributes. Then using Jsoup I would extract data and create an ArrayList, and then use logic to get data from the Arraylist.

I am skipping the Object creation (since it is not the issue here) and I will name the Object as `Machine`

Then using Jsoup I would get the row data like this:

```
ArrayList<Machine> list = new ArrayList();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
for (Element table : doc.select("table")) { //this will work if your doc contains only one table element
  for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
    Machine tmp = new Machine();
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    tmp.setClusterName(tds.get(3).text());
    tmp.setIp(tds.get(4).text());
    tmp.setStatus(tds.get(7).text());
    //.... and so on for the rest of attributes
    list.add(tmp);
  }
}
```

Then use a loop to get the values you need from the list:

```
for(Machine x:list){
  if(x.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("up")){
    //machine with UP status found
    System.out.println("The Machine with up status is:"+x.getHostName());
  }
}
```

That's all. Please also note that this code is not tested and may contain some syntactical errors as it is written directly on this editor and not in an IDE.

Comment: This doesn't consider the first line to be a headline, so use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710085/2470092

Answer (score 1):

The below is a clean generic function to extract an html table into a simple list map structure.

Pass the document to this function with table order asking for the nth table in the html page.

The function will not return accurate data if the table makes use of rowspan or colspan.

```
public static List<Map<String,String>> parseTable(Document doc, int tableOrder) {
    Element table = doc.select("table").get(tableOrder);
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");
    Elements first = rows.get(0).select("th,td");

    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Element header : first)
        headers.add(header.text());

    List<Map<String,String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    for(int row=1;row<rows.size();row++) {
        Elements colVals = rows.get(row).select("th,td");
        //check column size here

        int colCount = 0;
        Map<String,String> tuple = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(Element colVal : colVals)
            tuple.put(headers.get(colCount++), colVal.text());
        System.out.println(tuple.toString());
        listMap.add(tuple);
    }
    return listMap;
}
```